# Optimizing COUNT(DISTINCT) SQL query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables A, B:

A contains two columns and has a relatively small amount of rows compared to B (thousands):

```
id, build_id (string)
```

B contains three columns and has a large amount of rows (hundreds of thousands):

```
 id, build_id (string), task_id (string)
```

There may be many tasks for a given build. I would like to obtain a table containing all builds and the latest task id for each build and the number of tasks for that build. The query I have is below:

```
SELECT 
    A.build_id, 
    MAX(B.id) as latest_task_id, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT B.task_id) AS task_count 
FROM 
    A
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    B ON B.build_id = A.build_id 
GROUP BY 
    A.build_id
```

Is there any way to optimize this? There are already indexes on build_id and task_id.

**UPDATE**: This is on postgres 9.6+

Comment: which postgres version? this matters as you can optimise on 9.6+

Comment: MySQL and postgresql are two different products with different sql implementations. Which one do you use? Also, why do you need to optimise the query? Is it slow? If yes, how slow it is? What's roughly the number of affected records?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are really using.  I removed the incompatible database tags.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the execution plan generated using `explain (analyze, verbose, format text)`. [**Formatted text**](http://dba.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: is B.task_id unique in either table? (if so, creating a unique index might help)

Comment: task_id only exists in table B and it is not unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try aggregating before the `join`:

```
SELECT A.build_id, 
       MAX(B.id) as latest_task_id, 
       COUNT(B.task_id) AS task_count
FROM A LEFT OUTER JOIN
     (SELECT B.build_id, B.task_id, MAX(B.id) as id
      FROM B
      GROUP BY B.build_id, B.task_id
     ) B
     ON B.build_id = A.build_id
GROUP BY A.build_id;
```

Sometimes, the algorithms for overall aggregation are more efficient than for `COUNT(DISTINCT)`.

You can also try an index on `B(build_id, task_id, id)` for this query.

Comment: This query speeds it up a bit, thanks!. The covering index however didn't help.